# How can I navigate to a different page when user clicks a row?

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

I want to be able to navigate to a different page when user clicks are row.
***Problems***

- No error is thrown I can see the `selectionListener` getting executed with expected row value but nothing happens.
- Is this the right way of doing it i.e. using my action listener for this purpose.

Backing bean is this.
**Backing bean**

```
package com.howto;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
import javax.faces.model.DataModel;

import org.richfaces.component.UIExtendedDataTable;

@ManagedBean(name = "backingBean")
@SessionScoped
public class BackingBean {
    private List<String> names;
    private DataModel<String> name;
    private String rowValue;
   // private List<String> selection;
    private Collection<String> selection;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        names.add("MyName");
        names.add("YourName");
        names.add("OurName");
        names.add("MamaDidNotGiveOne");
    }

    public void update() {
        System.out.println("Somebody clicked "
                + name);
    }

    public List<String> getNames() {
        return names;
    }

    public void setNames(List<String> names) {
        this.names = names;
    }

    public DataModel<String> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(DataModel<String> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String selectionListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        UIExtendedDataTable dataTable = (UIExtendedDataTable) event.getComponent();
        Object originalKey = dataTable.getRowKey();
      //  selectionItems.clear();
        for (Object selectionKey : selection) {
            dataTable.setRowKey(selectionKey);
            if (dataTable.isRowAvailable()) {
                //selectionItems.add((InventoryItem) dataTable.getRowData());
                rowValue =  (String) dataTable.getRowData();
            }
        }        
        dataTable.setRowKey(originalKey);
        return "success";
    }

    public String gotopage() {
        return "success";
    }

    public Collection<String> getSelection() {
        return selection;
    }

    public void setSelection(Collection<String> selection) {
        this.selection = selection;
    }

    public String getRowValue() {
        return rowValue;
    }

    public void setRowValue(String rowValue) {
        this.rowValue = rowValue;
    }

}
```

Method `selectionListener`does get hit every time user clicks a row item no error is thrown but nothing happens.
**XHTML**

```
        <h:form>
            <rich:extendedDataTable
                value="#{backingBean.names}" var="rowItem"
                selection="#{backingBean.selection}" id="table"
                frozenColumns="2" style="height:300px; width:500px;" selectionMode="single">
                <a4j:ajax event="selectionchange" listener="#{backingBean.selectionListener}" />                    
                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="vendor" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{rowItem}" />
                </rich:column>
            </rich:extendedDataTable>
        </h:form>
```

**Navigation Rule**

```
<navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
         <navigation-case>
            <from-action>#{backingBean.selectionListener}</from-action>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pages/dummyfolder/results.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

---

*Using **Richfaces 4** could not find a tag with version.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't navigate by returning `String` from an action **listener** method. You can only do this in real action methods. You need to set the method return type back to `void` and take the navigation in your own hands with help of [`NavigationHandler#handleNavigation()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/NavigationHandler.html#handleNavigation%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
public void selectionListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    // ...

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(context, "#{backingBean.selectionListener}", "success");
}
```